# Swift - Programmatically set UITableViewCell resets on scroll

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

So I'm setting a UITableViewCell's layout programmatically when it is selected:

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView,  didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    self.selectedCellIndexPath = indexPath
    var selectedCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.endUpdates()
    var cell:SelectedPatientCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("patient selected", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SelectedPatientCell
    cell.patientName.text = patients[indexPath.row].fullName
    cell.dob.text = patients[indexPath.row].dob
    ...
    selectedCell = cell
}
```

And when I scroll the tableView, the layout of the cell resets to its original layout set in cellForRowAtIndexPath. However, the height stays as it should when I set it in the function above. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Here is an album of what's happening:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gj1eW.jpg

Image 1:original state

Image 2: selected state (how it should stay on scrolling)

Image 3: what actually happens

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is. Could you explain more about what you're trying to accomplish and what's going wrong? Are you trying to change the cell once it's selected?

Comment: so a cell has two states, unselected and selected. when it is selected and i scroll, it resets to the original layout. i will see if i can take some screenshots to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found my own solution:
Instead of doing

```
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.endUpdates()
```

I needed to do this at the end of the function:

```
    tableView.reloadData()
```

and that solves the issue

Answer (score 1):

you should hold this state in

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if indexPath == self.selectedCellIndexPath {
        var cell:SelectedPatientCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("patient selected", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SelectedPatientCell
        cell.patientName.text = patients[indexPath.row].fullName  
        cell.dob.text = patients[indexPath.row].dob
        return cell
    }
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("patient selected") as! OriCell
    ...
    return cell
 }
```

in this way if you scroll tableView,it won't resume to original Cell.
Hopefully it is clear.

Comment: do explain more for the user with a sample model so that it is helpful for everyone coming to the question later on

Comment: I reset my answer, please pick it